# Can I put a relatively deeply-nested tag at the bottom of the page with a media query?

Tags: css, media-queries

I could figure out a way how to do the following with JS. But I would like to keep people happy who don't enable JS.

I have all kinds of `<aside>` tags. For a large screen these tags can be displayed next to the blog post. For smaller screens I would like to put them below blog post. I am trying to figure out how to do it with CSS positioning, but the all text from the `<aside>` tags seem to stick to their positioning that their `<p>` tags have.

Would one know how to do this with CSS?

So imagine the following is a web page, then an example output would be for > 1024 px:

```
Lorem Ipsum [1] Lorem Ipsum  |     [1] Ipsum Ipsalla
Lorem Ipsum [1] Lorem Ipsum  |     [1] Ipsum Ipsalla
Lorem Ipsum [1] Lorem Ipsum  |     [1] Ipsum Ipsalla
```

Where | is a dotted line.

For < 1024px it would be:

```
Lorem Ipsum [1] Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum [1] Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum [1] Lorem Ipsum

Bibliography
[1] Ipsum Ipsalla
[1] Ipsum Ipsalla
[1] Ipsum Ipsalla
```

For the time being I don't display them. For context, this is what I have.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Merriweather", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Nimbus L", sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 300;
        line-height: 26px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 60%;
      }

      aside {
        position: absolute;
        width: 15%;
        left: 80%;
        margin-top: -50px;
        font-family: "Merriweather", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Nimbus L", sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 100;
        line-height: 15px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        border-left: dotted thin #000;
      }

      @media (max-width: 1024px) {
        aside {
          display: none;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum [1] <aside>[1] Ipsum Ipsalla</aside> Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum [1] <aside>[1] Ipsum Ipsalla</aside> Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum [1] <aside>[1] Ipsum Ipsalla</aside> Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit: the following link shows a proposal for which if it would have existed would have solved my problem: https://discourse.wicg.io/t/position-an-element-relatively-to-another-element-from-anywhere-in-the-dom/968

Comment: I'd also suggest yoo look into flexbox &/or CSS-Grid.

Comment: Didn't think of css-grid or flexbox. Thanks! Will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this isn't pretty but it is about graceful degradation. If that works, then I don't care about prettiness.

The best solution I found is to have two asides with exactly the same content at different places in the HTML document. One group has a class called `mobile`. When the media query is triggered, then all normal asides are on `display: none;` and show the `mobile` asides in the footer. If the media query is not triggered, then all `mobile` asides are on display none because they are in a nested footer tag.

The previous answer from amn did help me to make it a bit more semantic.